# How can I know the areas (in km2) of shapefiles distributed across the world (in R)?

Tags: r, gis, area, shapefile, r-maptools

I have a bunch of shapefiles contained in an object of the class:

```
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" attr(,"package") [1] "sp"
```

I would like to obtain the areas of these shapefiles in km2. Since these shapefiles are distributed across the globe, I have projected the shapefiles with an "equal areas" projection, namely: a Lambert Cylindrical Equal Area "+proj=cea +lon_0=-80", to make sure that areas won't be distorted by effect of the latitude.

I do this, in this way:

```
require(maptools)

data.shape<-readShapePoly("species_distributions.shp",proj4string=CRS("+proj=cea +lon_0=-80"))
```

And I calculate areas in this way:

```
sapply(slot(data.shape, "polygons"), slot, "area")->areas
```

However, the areas I obtain are weird... with values like this: 7.861879e-02 1.819334e+00 4.510745e+00. They just don't make sense...

What am I doing wrong? how could I get these areas in squared km? (considering that these shapefiles are distributed across the globe...)

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Tina.

Comment: readShapePoly does not reproject, you are basically assigning the wrong metadata. There are better tools, see readOGR in rgdal and gArea in rgeos - but still choosing the right target projection is more involved

Comment: Thank you, I'll check these functions. I guess that a  Lambert Cylindrical Equal Area would still be a right target project, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but is this what you were looking for?

```
require(geosphere)
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

polys = lapply(wrld_simpl@polygons, function(p) p@Polygons)

poly_areas = sapply(polys, function(p){
  coords = lapply(p, function(p) p@coords)
  ind_areas = lapply(coords, areaPolygon)
  sum(unlist(ind_areas))
})

data.frame(id = wrld_simpl@data$NAME, area = poly_areas/1e+06)
```